# Jmeter throwing 500 invalid character error for a Blaze meter recording

Tags: jmeter

I am facing an error on running a test on Blazemeter recording, below are the sample request and response  i am getting with error.

Error message :  "Invalid character '%' in input string"

> ```
> Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
> Sample Start: 2018-06-12 15:46:29 IST
> Load time: 1239
> Connect Time: 1073
> Latency: 1238
> Size in bytes: 448
> Sent bytes:730
> Headers size in bytes: 305
> Body size in bytes: 143
> Sample Count: 1
> Error Count: 1
> Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
> Response code: 500
> Response message: Invalid character '%' in input string
> ```

Request :
POST data:

> %7Bitems%3A%5B%7Bn%3A%27AuthenticationChannel.PrepareSessionForLogin%27%2Cps%3A%5B%7Bn%3A%27request%27%2Cv%3A%7B%22userName%22%3A%22settele%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D=

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Origin: https://crmtest*.*********.de
x-redirect: client
x-request: channelrpc;version=1.0
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://********.********.de/******/****/*****
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Length: 161
Host: ****test*.**********.**

Where I am missing to run this successfully ?

Thanks  & Regards,
Dev

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you post request is having some issue. Double check the post request. I have check you request in json validator and it shows issue with it.

[image]

I have used decoded request.

Hope it helps.